# How to create alias for git bash to make fast cd through directories

Tags: git, bash, cmd, git-bash

I'm using git bash and let say i have 2 folders: C:/folder1 and C:/folder2, I'd like to make fast cd from one to another.

I've tried git.alias but it seems to work for "git ..." commands only.. and I'm not very familiar with all this bash stuff.. so how should I do that?

Comment: or learn GNU Screen or tmux and have a windows with each directory open ... or even split the screen :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In bash you could do the following to create alias:

```
alias cdf1="cd /user/home/cloudera"
cd /user
cdf1
pwd
```

You will get result of pwd as /user/home/cloudera. You could do the same in git-bash prompt as well with directory as "C:/folder1" instead of "/user/home/cloudera".

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've tried 'alias' also, but i probably used wrong syntax.

Comment: Is there some way to permanently save that setting so that you don't have to retype it every time you open an instance of Git Bash?

Comment: @LauraS just define that alias in .bashrc file residing in your hole directory.

Comment: @almasshaikh, thanks. I defined it in .bash_profile and it's working great!

Answer (score 5):

*The following is to define aliases for Git Bash in Windows (MSYS Git)*

I finally managed to get `alias` for Git Bash working by placing a `.bash_profile` file in my Windows user home directory (`%USERPROFILE%`, typically `C:\Users\<username>\`) and adding the following to it (example):

```
alias cdf1="d/Folder/Another\ folder\ with\ spaces/Destination/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply define dos alias:

```
doskey cdf1=cd c:\folder1
doskey cdf2=cd c:\folder2
```

Then a simple `cdf1` would take you to the right folder, even in a [git-cmd](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) session.
In a [git-bash session](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs), you would need bash alias, but you don't need a bash session to use git.

Comment: @rubenvb it works in cmd, and you don't need bash to use git on Windows.

Comment: The question is about git bash.

Comment: @rubenvb hence my answer to point out that you don't have to use git bash (git itself needs bash to run its command, you don't)

Answer (score 2):

Windows users can create `.bashrc` file in their users folder and set aliases there:

`alias folder1='cd /c/folder1'`